# Is there a timeline of what type of a Brexit deal each party found acceptable over time?

Tags: united-kingdom, brexit

In the immediate aftermath of Brexit there has been a lot of posturing with numerous UK politicians demanding that the UK either gets a tailormade deal or quits outright without a deal, instead relying on free trade agreements with other countries. But as time passed it seems that the positions have shifted, with Labour currently calling for a Norway-like integration which would be nearly equivalent to not leaving the EU in the first place.

Is there an analysis of how the official position of each UK party shifted over time?

Comment: It's probably a bit meaningless given that the intra-party factionalism proved so strong on Brexit.

Answer (score 3):

The Labour position was set out in March 2017, shortly before the general election that year, and they have officially stuck to it: https://labourlist.org/2017/03/keir-starmer-labour-has-six-tests-for-brexit-if-theyre-not-met-we-wont-back-the-final-deal-in-parliament/

The important ones are in my opinion:

> 2. Does it deliver the “exact same benefits” as we currently have as members of the Single Market and Customs Union

It has become increasingly obviouis that the only way to achieve the “exact same benefits” as the single market is ... to stay in the single market.

> 5. Does it protect national security and our capacity to tackle cross-border crime?

This seems to be specifically referring to retaining the European Arrest Warrant, as well as security collaboration.

The Conservative party may have an official position on Brexit, but it's not relevant as both party whip and cabinet collective responsibility have collapsed. There is definitely a sub-faction which wants out of all EU institutions at any cost.

Comment: Worth noting that Labour based those tests on what the Tory government said were their aims before triggering Article 50, so they are the basis upon which Labour voted for the triggering. https://labour.org.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Theresa-Mays-failed-Brexit-plan-STRICTLY-EMBARGOED-UNTIL-2230-Monday-24-September.pdf

Answer (score 1):

UKIP under Nigel Farage [publicly supported a Norway style arrangement, but then switched to a hard brexit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNCwcTu9U6U). Farage subsequently left the party and started a new one, but both have retained their hard brexit stance.